# Create a sharepoint 2010 customlist form with javascript

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

i have a requirement that i need to create a sharepoint 2010 custom list view form. Iam having some drop down control in sharepoint form. i need to hide or show some divisions when drpdown item changed.Iam having a plan to create custom list from and write some javascript for dropdown even.

Can any one suggest me the way it can be done.

Thanks,
Suresh Pydi

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to customize list view form of SharePoint list you should to look at xslt template that is used for form rendering. You can customize it like describen in [this post](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html). If you would like to customize new/edit/view item form you should look at the form rendering template. You can create your own template and use it in your list. For more details look at [this post](http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2011/09/04/customizing-listitem-forms-using-renderingtemplates/).

If you would like to create cascade drop down boxes you can look at [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)